# OpenAI Gym step function doesn't work even after giving it 5 variables to unpack

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-gym

```
done = True
env.reset()
for step in range(5000):
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    done = terminated or truncated

    if done:
       env.reset()

env.close()
```

By running the following code as given by the official documentation, I still receive the outdated error

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/UsersProjects/GAME_AI_RL/Super_Mario/main.ipynb Cell 8 line 5
3 for step in range(5000):
4     action = env.action_space.sample()
----> 5     obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
6     done = terminated or truncated
8     if done:

File ~/miniforge3/envs/mlp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nes_py/wrappers/joypad_space.py:74, in JoypadSpace.step(self, action)
59 """
60 Take a step using the given action.
61
(...)
71
72 """
73 # take the step and record the output
---> 74 return self.env.step(self._action_map[action])

File ~/miniforge3/envs/mlp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/wrappers/time_limit.py:50, in TimeLimit.step(self, action)
39 def step(self, action):
40     """Steps through the environment and if the number of steps elapsed exceeds `max_episode_steps` then truncate.
41
42     Args:
(...)
...
---> 50     observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)
51     self._elapsed_steps += 1
53     if self._elapsed_steps >= self._max_episode_steps:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

System is MACOS M1, running on a virtual environment.

I first wrote 4 variables for unpacking a quick search told me it has been updated to 5, so I made it 5 however it still shows me the same error, I tried restarting the kernel, re installing the library, trying it out on a different python version.

Comment: If you changed the variables from 4 to 5 then why the error message said "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)"?

Comment: that is exactly why I am so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on the version of `gym(nasium)` you use, there are a couple of changes. Snce `gym` v0.26.0, there are 2 important changes regarding your problem:

> Step Termination / truncation - The Env.step function returns 5 values instead of 4 previously (observations, reward, termination, truncation, info).

You seem to have applied this already. Depending on the version, you might want to change it back to 4.

> Reset info - The Env.reset function returns two values (obs and info) with no return_info parameter for gym wrappers and environments. This is important for some environments that provided action masking information for each actions which was not possible for resets.

Resetting the environment now returns 2 values: `obs, info = env.reset(seed=None)`

Seeing however, that the gym-super-mario-bros environment uses an older version of `gym`, you have to adjust the amount of output variables to 4 and use an older version of `gym` to get this to work. This is thus a version `gym<0.26.0`